# Can i set the UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark on BarButton?

Tags: iphone

i want UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark the all cells of tableView while am touching the Bar Button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the cell accessory types in the method which you have given in the barbutton declaration.

Check this code. Follow like that

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(showChecked)];

- (void)showChecked{
isChecked = YES;
[tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use a bool variable isButtonClick;

and attach a action on barButton click says click;

so in click

```
-(void)click
{
  isButtonClick=YES;
  [yourTable reloadData];
}
```

now in cellforRowAtIndexPath

put condition

```
{
  //your code

  if(isButtonClick)
  {
     [yourTable setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
  }

}
```